# How do I position 'data-icon' elements inside buttons in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a div with the following jQuery attributes:

```
<div class="block" data-role="button" data-icon="home">

</div>
```

And heres the CSS:

```
        .block{
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
        }
```

The 'home' icon is in the top left of the button. How do I resize  / reposition it inside my button?

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/H8LMA/ why `<div>` not `<a>`? Please clarify your question.

Comment: My button is slightly bigger than that so thats not really what I want. I think i'll just make a custom image to fit my button size. Cheers for the help Omar!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="right">
```

--update

See live example [here](http://jsbin.com/aQUcuZU/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks, but this pushes the icon slightly outside the button to the top right.

Could my CSS be causing a problem?

Comment: Please add more details to your answer.

Comment: revenging is bad my friend.

Comment: @Daft not the css, your div should have some content, if not you need to set data attribute `data-iconpos="notext"`